# glNormal opengl - Square example

Tags: opengl

I am having difficulty figuring out how to calculate normal, I think I have some misunderstandings so I would like to give an example of a piece of simple geometry and figure out the normal in which case it should be a little clearer how to do it with harder geometry.

```
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
       glVertex3f(1,1,-1);
       glVertex3f(1,1,1);
       glVertex3f(-1,1,1);
       glVertex3f(-1,1,-1);
    glEnd();
```

At every vertex I know I need to put in a normal value (I want to light this) so this represents a front facing square (2 x 2). So before every vertex would I have a normal of (0, 1.0, 0)?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When you need to calculate the *normal* of a *quad* you need to calculate the *cross-product* of your quad's 4 vertices.

```
A = (1, 1, -1)
B = (1, 1, 1)
C = (-1, 1, 1)
D = (-1, 1, -1)
```

This is how your quads vertices are laid out. The reason I'm adding this, is because the order you calculate the following vertices in, is important!

```
A----B
|    |
|    |
D----C
```

So now when you want to calculate the normal, you simply need to do.

```
normal = (C - A) x (D - B)
```

*Where x means cross-product.*

### Cross-Product

In case you don't know what a *cross-product* is or how to calculate it, then here I will show you how to calculate it.

```
V1 = (C - A)
V2 = (D - B)
```

Then we calculate the *cross-product* by doing the following.

```
normal.x = V1.y * V2.z - V1.z * V2.y
normal.y = V2.x * V1.z - V2.z * V1.x
normal.z = V1.x * V2.y - V1.y * V2.x
```

Where the above 3 lines is the equivalent of writing.

```
normal = V1 x V2
```

Now we've calculated the *cross-product*, which in this case is a 3D Vector.

#### Extra

If you didn't know what a *cross-product* is, and want to read more about it, then you can read more about it on these two links.

- [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product)
- [Wolfram - Math World](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CrossProduct.html)

### Edit

> I did the cross product, it is normal = (0, 8, 0), if I normalize it I get (0, 1, 0)

Just to clarify something for you, the reason we need to normalize the normal, is because we're calculating the normal distribution of `x, y, z,` between `0 <-> 1`

If you want to normalize a vector you would do the following.

```
length = sqrt(x * x + y * y + z * z)

if (length > 0) {
    x /= length
    y /= length
    z /= length
}
```

Also if you want to check if you need to normalize a vector or not, you can do the following.

```
if ((x * x + y * y + z * z) != 1) {
    // NORMALIZE THE VECTOR
}
```

> Now does that mean I only need to put it once over the vertices or do I need to mention it for every vertex in the quad.

**First Way**

```
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glNormal3f(0, 1, 0);
    glVertex3f(1, 1, -1);
    glVertex3f(1, 1, 1);
    glVertex3f(-1, 1, 1);
    glVertex3f(-1, 1, -1);
glEnd();
```

**Second Way**

```
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glNormal3f(0, 1, 0);
    glVertex3f(1, 1, -1);
    glNormal3f(0, 1, 0);
    glVertex3f(1, 1, 1);
    glNormal3f(0, 1, 0);
    glVertex3f(-1, 1, 1);
    glNormal3f(0, 1, 0);
    glVertex3f(-1, 1, -1);
glEnd();
```

It doesn't really matter if you do it the first or the second way. **As long as** your quad is plain, so if it's completely flat you can do either the first or second way.

**Though** if your quad isn't completely flat, then you need to do the second way, because then each vertex of the quad will/might have a different normal.

> Many resources says you need to calculate the normal for every vertex though.

That is true, though as I said above, if you calculating a normal for a completely flat quad, then the normal for each vertex will be the same, therefore you can save some calculation/time/CPU by simply only calculating the normal once and using it for each vertex, as long as possible.

Comment: Thank you very much ... I okay I did the cross product, it is normal = (0, 8, 0), if I normalize it I get (0, 1, 0), now does that mean I only need to put it once over the vertices or do I need to mention it for every vertex in the quad. I'm sorry if this all sounds like dumb questions but I have never dealt with opengl before. Many resources says you need to calculate the normal for every vertex though.

Comment: @InsigMath look at my edited answer, I answer the questions you commented.

Comment: thank you for the more detailed response, this will help a whole lot!